# Log in is broken

Tags: support, login

I primarily use IE11.  I visit StackOverflow several times a day, and just leave it logged in.  Closing and reopening the browser logs me back in automatically.

IE just crashed on me.  When I brought it back up, I was no longer automatically logged in to StackOverflow.  I guess my cookie got destroyed in the crash.  Oh well.

But, when I try to login, the login page does not work in IE.  Neither the "more login options" link or the "Log in" button respond to mouse clicks! I use my own domain for OpenID, with StackExchange as the OpenID provider.

I brought up FireFox and was able to enter and submit my OpenID credentials, but I got a "Message signature incorrect" error from the server.  I refreshed the page and it then logged me in OK.

Looks like something is broken on StackExchange's end. Any ideas?

**Update**: "*I guess my cookie got destroyed in the crash*" - or not. I just restarted IE after using FireFox for awhile, and IE automatically logged in to StackOverflow normally again.

Comment: I remember someone saying that IE just don't know how to manage cookies... clear them with a 3rd party tool, and you should be good to go.